# show Query mysql with condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table employee below:

```
+-------------+---------+------------------+
| employee_id |  phone  |       dept       |
+-------------+---------+------------------+
|           1 | 7738474 | marketing        |
|           2 | [null]  | marketing        |
|           3 | 9938475 | customer service |
|           4 | 4233474 | customer service |
|           5 | 1738477 | marketing        |
|           6 | [null]  | marketing        |
|           7 | [null]  | customer service |
+-------------+---------+------------------+
```

and i want if marketing dept have null phone value they are not shown
and if customer service dept, they shown all value even phone is null

```
+-------------+---------+------------------+
| employee_id |  phone  |       dept       |
+-------------+---------+------------------+
|           1 | 7738474 | marketing        |
|           3 | 9938475 | customer service |
|           4 | 4233474 | customer service |
|           5 | 1738477 | marketing        |
|           7 | [null]  | customer service |
+-------------+---------+------------------+
```

any possible query without use union?

```
select * from employee where dept ='customer service'
union ALL 
select * from employee where dept = 'marketing' and phone is not null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like relatively simple filtering:

```
select *
from employee e
where dept = 'customer service' or
      (dept = 'marketing' and phone is not null)
```